# powershell - IE checkbox not being recognised

Tags: powershell

Recently i've created a powershell script for one of our monitoring systems, the script automates the loading of a webpage, logging in with user credentials and submitting the credentials to load the dashboard page.

Once the credentials are verified and the dashboard page loads, there's a checkbox for "auto-extend session" (the session by default timesout after 30 minutes of inactivity).

I have also attempted to automate the checking of the checkbox. From what I can see, the check successfully applies, when I get the status of the element the checked value shows as "True" - however after 30 minutes, the system logs out automatically. If I apply the tick to the checkbox manually, it works fine with no timeout after 30 minutes.

I'm using IE11 on Windows 7 x86.

Has anyone ever come across this before?

part of the powershell script that applies the check:
`$varHEAchk = $ie.Document.getElementByID("extend-session-checkbox").checked = $true`

i've checked the element afterwards and it does state:

> checked: True

some of the HTML code of the checkbox:

```
<input id="extend-session-checkbox" style="margin: -2px 4px 0px 0px;" type="checkbox" />
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the checked attribute to the string value of `checked` instead of the boolean `$true`

```
$ie.Document.getElementByID("extend-session-checkbox").checked = "checked"
```

To find out if the box is checked you can use

```
if($ie.Document.getElementByID("extend-session-checkbox").checked)
```

You could also consider having the box checked by default:

```
<input id="extend-session-checkbox" style="margin: -2px 4px 0px 0px;" type="checkbox" checked />
```

Comment: how bizarre, it still isn't working. I amended the attributre from boolean $true to "checked" and also ran an if statement (echoing "checkbox is checked") if true. The checkbox was checked and the script echo'd it was ok. But again after 30 minutes, it times out.

Comment: Ok, i'm afraid setting the checkbox to "checked" is one thing, but after that the form needs to be submitted. This can be quite tricky.. You need to find the form's `action` url and if that is a relative url you will have to transform that into a absolute url. Maybe performing a  `$ie.Document.Forms[0].submit()` after setting the checkbox works?

Comment: I have also seen solutions to submit the form like this: First get the form in a Powershell variable `$form = $ie.Document.Forms[0]`. Next set the field(s) in there `$form.fields["extend-session-checkbox"] = "checked"`. Finally submit using a Post request: `$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri '<YOUR FORMS ACTION URL>' -Method POST -Body $form.fields -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`